# How could I fix pgfplots' clash with powerdot's clock option?

Tags: pgfplots, powerdot

The clock option is a useful feature of powerdot in case you would like to follow your presentation time and also visualize a clock for your attendance. As far as I see, a recent update in pgfplots clashes with powerdot. The issue arose after a pgfplots update but the output seems like the error is in powerdot.cls.

In essence, when pgfplots package is included and clock option of powerdot is activated; the first run of LaTeX interrupted unexpectedly. However, an aux file is generated. In the second run, the aux file becomes effective and compilation succeed. I believe the priority of reference insertion is somehow broken.

I provide the MWE and the faulty compilation result below:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[clock]{powerdot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{slide}{Slide}
    Content
  \end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Faulty response:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastslide' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.

[1]
! Undefined control sequence.
\pd@item ...\pd@@type \fi \ifnum \pd@currentstate
                                                  =\z@ \normalcolor \pst@Ver...
l.8 \end{document}

?
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: I had the same error, but it disappeared after the second `latex` run.

Comment: Also, there is no error on the *first* `latex`run if one omits package `pgfplots`.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, exactly. If you generate the aux file the error disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the situation is not so recent and MWE is reproducible even in TeXLive 2020.

The error seems like a result of uninitialized overlays at least on one of the slides. Therefore, a possible workaround is adding a dummy pause at the end.

So, the following seems to be compiling successfully.

```
\documentclass[clock]{powerdot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{slide}{Slide}
    Content
    \pause% <--- Here is the dummy pause
  \end{slide}
\end{document}
```